# Looking for a more universal onUserInteraction() event - not just in one Activity

Tags: android, events

I need to be able to know when the user is not interacting with the tablet/phone for a period of time.  I am currently attempting to gain this intelligence using:

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){ 
    lastInteraction = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

However, it only fires with direct interaction of the Activity (or fragment in said Activity), not any displayed dialogs.  Is there a more universal way to achieve this without adding this to every dialog?

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Best way I've ever used is to check time between onResume and onPause methods for this purpose. But I really wonder the answers for this question. And +1 For your question.

Comment: If the app keeps screen on - which it does, inactivity will not trigger the `onPause()` event.  That will only fire when they back out of the app or hit home button.  So, yes then inactivity monitoring will stop.  But I need to do something if they just don't interact whilst the app is still open.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by wrapping dialogs into custom layout:

```
public class InteractionInterceptorLayer extends LinearLayout {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        //any actions here...

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    //constructors...
}
```

And in layout definition:

```
<com.package.InteractionInterceptorLayer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    // layout goes here

</com.package.InteractionInterceptorLayer>
```